# Tortoise Merge - not a working copy error

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, patch

I am trying to use Tortoise Merge to apply a patch file, generated from WinMerge, to a new file to get an updated file. I've looked at questions/answers on here, but I am getting an error about the selected directory not being a working directory, even if I follow the example of setting my desktop as the working directory. Can anyone help?
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Have you tried to generate a patch using TortoiseSVN?